# XE2: Issues with TGridPanel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tgridpanel

I've created the following `TGridPanel` in the IDE:

[image]

This `TGridPanel` is inside a `TPageControl:TTabSheet`, which is on a `TFrame`.

```
TFrame => TPageControl => TTabSheet => TGridPanel
```

During Design Time in the IDE everything is fine.

However, when I drop the `TFrame` on empty (main) form and then hit the Compile button, all `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` settings I made in the `TFrame` are reset when the compilation finishes.

When I then run the application, I get an `EGridPanelException` saying:

> Error reading ...Panel_Setup_Content.ColumnCollection: Cannot delete a
>   column that contains controls

and the application terminates after hitting "OK".

Additionally, when I close the project and re-open it (with the `TFrame` dropped on the main form), I get the exact same error + "Ignore the error and continue ? Note: Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values to be lost."

When I use Notepad to remove the TFrame from the main Form DFM I can open the project again and also the TFrame file without error messages or problems.

The problems occur as soon as I drop the `TFrame` on the main form.

Is this a Delphi issue ? Or is it me doing something wrong ?